# Invert get_matching_blocks results from difflib in python 2.7 and get MISMATCHED blocks

Tags: python, python-2.7, difflib

The following python 2.7 example returns the matching blocks between string1 and string2:

```
import difflib    

string1 = "This is a test"
string2 = "This ain't a testament"

s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x == " ", string1, string2)

for block in s.get_matching_blocks():
    a,b,size = block
    print "string1[%s] and string2[%s] match for %s characters" % block
```

Here are the results from above program:

```
string1[0] and string2[0] match for 5 characters
string1[5] and string2[6] match for 1 characters
string1[7] and string2[10] match for 7 characters
string1[14] and string2[22] match for 0 characters
```

I want to invert the results and return the mismatched blocks for string1 and string2 as follows:

```
string1[6] mismatch for 1 characters

string2[5] mismatch for 1 characters
string2[7] mismatch for 3 characters
string2[17] mismatch for 5 characters
```

Note: the total matching blocks is the same for both strings, but the mismatched blocks will vary depending on the strings.

Here is color coded representation of the strings where black=matched and red=mismatched.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that it should be possible to walk thru the matched blocks to compute the unmatched portions. A quick solution (read as "tested only with the input in the question") is pasted below. See if it helps you work out the final solution.

*Note*: I only have access to a Python3 interpreter right now but as this question is not version-specific, I'm posting this solution.

```
import difflib

string1 = "This is a test"
string2 = "This ain't a testament"

s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x == " ", string1, string2)

s1_miss = list()
s2_miss = list()
s1_cur_off = 0
s2_cur_off = 0
for block in s.get_matching_blocks():
    a,b,size = block
    print("string1[%s] and string2[%s] match for %s characters" % block)
    if a > s1_cur_off:
        s1_miss.append((s1_cur_off, a-1, a-1-s1_cur_off + 1))
    s1_cur_off = a + size
    if b > s2_cur_off:
        s2_miss.append((s2_cur_off, b-1, b-1-s2_cur_off + 1))
    s2_cur_off = b + size
print(s1_miss)
print(s2_miss)
```

Output: 
A list of mismatches is dumped for each string. Each element of the list has three-tuples: the start and end offsets of the mismatch and the length (mostly for debugging).

```
string1[0] and string2[0] match for 5 characters
string1[5] and string2[6] match for 1 characters
string1[7] and string2[10] match for 7 characters
string1[14] and string2[22] match for 0 characters
[(6, 6, 1)]
[(5, 5, 1), (7, 9, 3), (17, 21, 5)]
```

Comment: This worked for me trying to find bits of two different disk images that differed.  Thanks!